# Enviar archivos adjuntos con email JS

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, email, nodemailer

estoy intentando hacer un formulario con React usando la librería EmailJs (https://www.emailjs.com/docs/user-guide/file-attachments/) y todo funciona perfectamente hasta que quiero adjuntar un archivo. La documentación es muy simple pero no entiendo porque no me funciona ni el ejemplo siguiendo los 2 simples pasos que hay.

Si pudieran echarme un cable se lo agradezco.
Les dejo un par de fotos donde muestro lo que he intentado.
Gracias.
[image: Código en reactJs],[image: Configuración de emailJs]

```
import React from 'react'
import { Form,Accordion } from "react-bootstrap";
import emailjs from 'emailjs-com';
import './Form.css';
export default function Form3() {
    function sendEmail(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
       

        emailjs.sendForm(****,****,e.target,********).then(res=>{
            console.log(res);
            window.location.reload();
            alert("mensaje enviado con éxito, en breve recibirá una confirmación de su pedido. Gracias")

        }).catch(err=> console.log(err));
    }
    return (
        <div>
          <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" onSubmit={sendEmail}>
    <label>Attach file:</label>
    <input type="file" name="my_file" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: ¿Y que error te da?  ¿Puedes poner el codigo en modo texto?  Las [imagenes con código](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/263200) estan muy mal vistas aqui..  Léete [ask] y haz el [tour] para aprender como funcionamos y así podras seguir las normas del sitio y podremos ayudarte mejor, gracias.

Comment: no me da ningún error simplemente me envía el texto pero no me adjunta ningún archivo.

Comment: te adjunto el código en la pregunta. Gracias